# Returning object attributes from C# function to Blazor web elements

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side

I am trying to initialize a new object in C#, and then print the attributes of the newly created object into a `<p>` tag.  I am stuck on how I would go about taking the generated object from:

```
<button type="button" @onclick="@(() => createSword("steel"))">
```

```
And being able to use it in my web app. 


@page "/authors"

<h3>Authors</h3>


<button type="button" @onclick="@(() => createSword("steel"))">Click me to generate a new sword</button>

<p> Current Sword: </p> <p id="generatedSword">My Sword Details here</p>

@{ <p> Hello </p>
        }

@code {

    public Object createSword(string x)
    {
        Sword testSword = new Sword(x);
        return testSword;
        
    }
    public class Sword
    {
        //Defining attributes of sword
        public int damage;
        public String statType;
        public int stat;
        public String name;

        //Defining private variables of sword

        public Sword(string typeOfSword)
        {
            if (typeOfSword == "Steel")
            {
                damage = 5;
                name = "Steel Sword";
                statType = "Strength";
                stat = 2;

            }
            if (typeOfSword == "Bone")
            {
                damage = 10;
                name = "Bone Sword";
                statType = "Strength";
                stat = 5;

            }
            if (typeOfSword == "Glowing")
            {
                damage = 20;
                name = "Glowing Sword";
                statType = "Strength";
                stat = 10;

            }

            if (typeOfSword == null)
            {
                damage = 1;
                name = "None";
                statType = "None";
                stat = 0;
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Would I have to assign it to a global object before doing so? I believe this could be circumvented when I create the player class and I could just print the player data in these fields since the player object would be a unique persistent object. Thoughts?

Comment: Yeah your issue here man was just using Object. If you have type Sword as Shaun shows below then you can just have that as a local variable in the code section, then your html elements bind to the local variabled. Think of the code section as your ViewModel. Stick variables there. Bind html to the variables. Add code to work on the variables and Blazor will do its magic to make sure the job gets done updating the UI.

Answer (score 1):

Does this answer your question (it seems too simple)?

I've changed your type of sword to an `emun` and added the object creator as a static method to the `Sword` class.

The object created is in the private field `generatedSword`.

```
@page "/"
<h3>Authors</h3>


<button type="button" @onclick="() => CreateSword(Sword.SwordType.Steel)">Click me to generate a new sword</button>

@if (generatedSword != null)
{
    <p> Current Sword: @generatedSword.name</p>
}
@{
    <p> Hello </p>
}

@code {
    private Sword generatedSword;

    private void CreateSword(Sword.SwordType typeOfSword)
    => generatedSword = Sword.NewSword(typeOfSword);

    public class Sword
    {
        //Defining attributes of sword
        public int damage;
        public String statType;
        public int stat;
        public String name;

        //Defining private variables of sword

        public Sword(SwordType typeOfSword)
        {
            if (typeOfSword == SwordType.Steel)
            {
                damage = 5;
                name = "Steel Sword";
                statType = "Strength";
                stat = 2;

            }
            if (typeOfSword == SwordType.Bone)
            {
                damage = 10;
                name = "Bone Sword";
                statType = "Strength";
                stat = 5;

            }
            if (typeOfSword == SwordType.Glowing)
            {
                damage = 20;
                name = "Glowing Sword";
                statType = "Strength";
                stat = 10;

            }

            if (typeOfSword == SwordType.None)
            {
                damage = 1;
                name = "None";
                statType = "None";
                stat = 0;
            }
        }

        public enum SwordType {None, Steel, Bone, Glowing};

        public static Sword NewSword(SwordType typeOfSword)
            => new Sword(typeOfSword);

    }

}
```